# How to find first instance in a column in excel and then reset it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to find the first instance where the value is >=65 in a column. The first flagged value can re-occur in the list and should be flagged again. Please see image for desired output.... I need the value of 1 every time the cell in "Data" is >=65 and < the first flagged value. All other cells should be zero. Please help.

[image]

Comment: "I need the value of 1 *everytime* the cell in "Data" is >=65" then why 69, 70, 66, 72 and 78 are 0?

Comment: Your specification in text and in  table not corresponds, and contains statements which contradict. Pls. clarify the specification of the requested result.

Comment: This might make sense if the intention had been "The **first flagged** value can re-occur in the list and should be flagged again....I need the value of 1 everytime the cell in "Data" is >=65 **and < the first flagged value**."

Comment: @user11222393, i've edited my explanation. Hope its more clear

Comment: I've posted some formulas you may try, but your statements are still contradictory. First you say "he first flagged value can re-occur in the list and should be flagged again.", but later you say "Data" is >=65 and < the first flagged value." so first flagged value will not be flagged again.

Comment: @user17243359 are you really using `Excel 2010` or `Excel 2007`? If yes I have provided some solutions do check them out. Thanks

Comment: @user17243359 have you tried the formulas yet the one I have posted, it works exactly the one you needed

Answer (score 2):

Are you really using **`Excel-2010`** or **`Excel-2007`** as per tagged? Perhaps with **`MS365`** you can use <kbd>SCAN( )</kbd> and <kbd>LET( )</kbd> function to resolve. For older version, is right after the **`MS365`** Solution.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(α,SCAN(0,A2:A17,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y>=65,x+1,0))),IF((α>1)+(α=0),0,1))
```

---

For Older Versions one could use the following formulas with the help of **auxiliary/helper** columns:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd> --> **For Helper/Auxiliary Column**

```
=(A2>=65)*(N(B1)+1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd> --> **For Output**

```
=N(NOT(OR(B2>1,B2=0)))
```

---

Or, you can use the below one as well for cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(B2>1,B2=0),0,1)
```

---

OfCourse you need to fill down the above formulas in older versions.

---

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365 you can try:

```
=LET(b,A1:A15,a,BYROW(b,LAMBDA(x,N(COUNTIF(A1:x,">=65")=1))),(a+BYROW(b,LAMBDA(z,IF(AND(z>=65,z<SUMPRODUCT(b,a)),1,0)))))
```

[image]

With older versions I would suggest making helper column. Formula in `B1` to be dragged down:

```
=N((COUNTIF($A$1:A1,">=65")=1))
```

And then formula in `C1` to be dragged down:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=65,A1<SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$15,$B$1:$B$15)),1,0)+B1
```

Result:

[image]